# docker-compose build generate failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7080

Tags: docker

After lot of building docker compose project, now my docker-compose build refuse to build because:

```
failed to fetch oauth token: Post "https://auth.docker.io/token:
proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7080
```

when I launch docker-compose build

I try this to know who use 7080 TCP port : `netstat -ano | findstr :7080`
And I have result only during docker-compose run (just after throw error the result of this command is empty) :

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:56487        127.0.0.1:7080         SYN_SENT        3184

 TCP    127.0.0.1:56488        127.0.0.1:7080         SYN_SENT        3184
```

I try this command to know which program is this 3184 PID but nothing result (same if docker-compose run) : `tasklist /fi "pid eq 3184"`

My Windows taskManager show nothing.

I also try to connect into docker hub with : `docker login` (connected correctly)

I found nothing information about 7080 port or 3184 PID program...

I also use **TCPView** or **Cports** program to found those but nothing

technical context :

- OS : windows 11 family
- docker desktop : 4.19.0

Answer (score 0):

`SYN_SENT` basically means that OS allocated this port for TCP connection. This port is completely random, selected by OS (there is some range but still), so do not try to find anything about this specific port or PID.

I suggest you reading [this article](http://karunsubramanian.com/network/what-is-syn_sent-socket-status/). Once the PID allocated this port dies, you no longer see this `SYS_SENT` socket, which is perfectly reasonable.

Regarding the question itself, if you have `SYN_SENT`, in overwhelming amount of cases that means the **network connectivity issue**. Basiaclly, the error messages that you posted means - docker have tried to establish TCP connection with the **auth.docker.io** host, OS allocated 7080 port for it, but still it got nothing back in response from **auth.docker.io** host. Check if you can connect to this host from the docker-compose environment, like:

```
telnet auth.docker.io
```

Most likely it would fail, and if did, than you at least know where to dig further, because network issues can be because whole hell of reasons...

Comment: this url https://auth.docker.io/token run correctly into browser but with telnet nothing. I don't understand if I need config proxy or not and how do this.....

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you:
1- Check for conflit to see if any programs or services are using this port (you can use TCPView to identify)
2- Check your firewall and security settings.(you can temporily disable)

Comment: Like I said I already check if port is used, and nothing program use this. Firewall disable I already trying to test and nothing change. Sorry but this is obvious way that already done. Issue seems to be more complex like that.